# Show that the problem has unique KKT points for maximization problem $\max c_1x_1 + ... + c_nx_n$

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Consider the following maximization problem: $$\max \; c_1x_1 + ... + c_nx_n$$ subject to the constraints $$x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2 \leq 1 $$
$$x_1, .... , x_n \geq 0$$
where $c_1,...,c_n$ are constants such that at least one of them is positive
(a) Show that the problem has a unique KKT point $x^*$ and find an explicit formula for it that expresses the coordinates $x_i^*$ in terms of the constants $c_1,...,c_n$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: you have a linear objective function over non-linear constraints. Try thinking what this implies regarding the optimal solution and why it means it will be unique. You can draw a 2-D sketch to get some intuition